# Xamarin WebView local page - why separate resources per platform

Tags: webview, resources, xamarin.forms

I need to display a local page in xamarin forms. I followed this documentation: [Xamarin working with WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/webview/) and I use following code to display a page:

```
private void DisplayLocalPage(string filename)
{

    HtmlWebViewSource htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();

    var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
    html.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();

    html.Html = ReadFile(filename);
    MyWebView.Source = html;
}
```

The page uses css in separate files - according to documentation, I have to use dependency service to make possible for each platform to reach css files.

So my project looks like this:

- TestWebView (Portable):

  - Resources:

    - local_page.html
    - stylesheet.css
- TestWebView:Droid

  - Assets:

    - stylesheet.css
- TestWebView:iOS

  - Resources:

    - stylesheet.css

As long as I can have html only in portable project, why do I have to use platform-specific resources for css? And is there any way to store the css also only once? The documentation didn't mention that.